# Test that a array contains elements with JUnit and AssertJ

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I have followings Unit Test with JUnit 4.12 and AssertJ 3.11.0 and having interesting results. `helloTest` is `green` but `worldTest` is `red`.

```
@Test
public void helloTest() {
    Object[] array = new Object[2];
    String[] firstElement = new String[]{"Hello"};
    String[] secondElement = new String[]{"World"};
    array[0] = firstElement;
    array[1] = secondElement;
    assertThat(array).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(firstElement, secondElement);
}

@Test
public void worldTest() {
    Object[] array = new Object[1];
    String[] element = new String[]{"Hello"};
    array[0] = element;
    assertThat(array).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(element);
}
```

And the result from AssertJ is

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: 
 Expecting:
   <[["Hello"]]>
 to contain exactly in any order:
   <["Hello"]>
 elements not found:
   <["Hello"]>
 and elements not expected:
   <[["Hello"]]>
```

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of types. The following test will pass:

```
@Test
public void worldTest() {
    String[][] array = new String[1][];
    String[] element = new String[]{"Hello"};
    array[0] = element;
    assertThat(array).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(element);
}
```

Your `worldTest` fails because you are trying to assert that an object of type `Object[]` contains an element of type `String[]`. You are making this assertion using a method with this declaration:

```
ObjectArrayAssert<ELEMENT> containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT... values)
```

This method expects the incoming type to match the type under inspection. In my example above this is true and hence the test passes. In your version of `worldTest` this is not true because one type is a `String[]` and the other type is an `Object[]`.